# Abstract Mathematics - Group theory and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I have been trying to solve two problems, but I am stuck. Can anybody provide me with some links or theory to solve the following problems? The problems are from a study guide and the test exercises are really similar to the ones presented here.

1) Are $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ isomorphic?

2) Are $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ isomorphic?

Comment: Can you find an element of order $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_5?$ Can you find an element of order $54$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_9$?

Comment: You can define an isomorphism $\phi (m,n) = 2m + 5n \pmod {10}$ in the first case. Can you think why this may not happen in the other case ?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, consider the element $(1,1)$ in $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_5$ (under addition modulo $2$ in the first coordinate, and modulo $5$ in the second coordinate). What is its order?

The second question is more subtle-consider what happens to the element $(a,b) \in \Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_9$, when we add it to itself $18$ times (note that $6|18$ and $9|18$). What does this tell you about the maximum possible order of elements of $\Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_9$?

Answer (score 0):

1) Since $2$ and $5$ are coprime and  $2 \times 5 = 10$, this is a direct result of the Chinese remainder theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement

You can do the same for the second case. ($6$ and $9$ not coprime so ...)

See page 12 for a proof : http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/numbertheory.pdf

Comment: "You can do the same for the second case"?

Comment: You cannot do the same since .....

Comment: You can do the same reasonning, but since the theorem is iff, itwill show that is not isomorphic...